# where to add the aria-modal attribute?

Tags: reactjs, accessibility, wai-aria

So I have a project in React where the modal does not have the proper markup.

I know I need to have `aria-modal="true"`, but I am not 100% sure if this attribute is added everywhere I have a `className`. So for example:

```
renderModal() {
    return (
      <Modal
        isOpen={this.props.isOpen}
        onRequestClose={this.toggleModal}
        contentLabel="Address Book"
        className={this.props.parentClassName ? 
            this.props.parentClassName + " address-modal" :
            "address-modal"}
        role="dialog"
      >
        {this.renderAddressForm()}
      </Modal>
    );
  }

  renderAddressForm(){
    return(
      <div className={this.props.parentClassName ? "form-"+this.props.parentClassName : null}>
        <h2 className="modal-title">{this.props.title}</h2>
```

Do I add `aria-modal="true"` in all the elements with a `className`? Such as `<Modal>`, `<div>`, `<h2>`?

I have read the documentation on ARIA 1.1 that says "The aria-modal attribute is used to indicate that the presence of a "modal" element precludes usage of other content on the page.", but I am not sure how to apply it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `aria-modal` attribute goes on the same element as the `role=dialog`