# focus moving out of modal in scan mode

Tags: javascript, angular, modal-dialog, accessibility

I am trying to fix an accessibility bug for screen reader in an Angular2 web application(SAP). The problem is in SCAN MODE with Edge, when the modal is open and using up and down arrows to travel through focusable elements, the focus moving out to the area outside the modal. However, in normal mode, if tabbing through elements in the modal, the focus never goes out of the modal.

The goal is to achieve the same experience as normal mode in scan mode.

Here is the structure of modal with other components, for example the modal is part of componentA:

componentA.html

```
<div>
<form>
</form>
<modal-window></modal-window>
</div>
```

The componentA is the body of the html page. The html page also contains other components i.e. the header component and footer component.
The modal is NOT implemented by dialog, but a div and it uses variable to control if the div should be visible or not.

What is the right way to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 0):

If you make your modal window a "sibling" of your main page, then you can add [`aria-hidden`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#aria-hidden) to the main window and that will prevent the up/down arrow keys from navigating outside the modal.

Initially hidden modal window:

```
<body>
  <div>
    <!-- main page -->
  </div>
  <div style="display:none">
    <!-- modal window -->
  </div>
</body>
```

Visible modal window

```
<body>
  <div aria-hidden="true">
    <!-- main page -->
  </div>
  <div style="display:block">
    <!-- modal window -->
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: It is very difficult to make the modal a 'sibling' of my main page. I would like to know any other suggestions?

Comment: I found a attribute called aria-modal and based on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51600621/where-to-add-the-aria-modal-attribute, if using aria-modal="true" and role="dialog" together for the modal div,  things should work. However, for me, it does not seem to work. I am not sure if I miss anything.

Comment: Ideally, aria-modal is the way to do it but it’s not supported yet.  You have to use aria-hidden

Comment: It is not possible for me to change the overall structure of code base. Any other workaround for this problem?

Comment: The only way to prevent the screen reader arrow keys from moving outside the modal is to set `aria-hidden` on everything else.  Having "sibling" DOM elements is the easiest way to set it once but if you can't arrange your code that way, then you  may have to set `aria-hidden` on several elements.

Comment: I have tried using aria-hidden for several elements, but the focus can move to the whole window, browser search bar and elements in the same line. I also tried setting aria-hidden for the whole body, but it did not seem to work as well.  May I know what I should do in this case?

Comment: You can't hide the browser's address bar and such.  You only have control over what's in your page.  Setting `aria-hidden` will hide the element on the page from the screen reader.  It works great.  I use it all the time.

Comment: I am sorry that I should be more clear that I did not hide anything other than the elements inside the body. I think the reason it did not work is that I cannot aria-hidden all possible area other than the modal itself because of the code structure. I am giving up on this solution.

Comment: Another idea I am trying right now is to disable for example the up arrow key for the first element(e.g. a button) in the modal so that the focus will not go out of the modal. I used the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54014662/how-to-disable-a-key-when-a-button-is-focused/54014813?noredirect=1#comment94866836_54014813 . However, it seems to me that the focus in scan mode is not the same as in normal mode. I can see the focus is on the button, and I pressed the up arrow key, but it never trigger the onKeydown() function.

Comment: In normal mode that is without the narrator turned on, if the focus is on the button, pressing up arrow key triggers the onKeydown() function. I would like to know does the focus in two different cases different? Is there a way I can make the focus in scan mode trigger the onKeydown() function?

Comment: No.  When the screen reader is in browse mode (instead of forms mode), you don't get arrow events.  That's intentional so you don't mess up normal screen reader behavior.  It's a simple solution to your problem.  Set `aria-hidden` on any elements you don't want the screen reader's arrow keys to get to.  The higher up the DOM you can set it, the easier it is.