# How to disable a key when a button is focused

Tags: angular, event-handling, keyboard-events, dom-events

How to disable the up arrow key when a button is focused and enable it when the button is not focused in angular2?
For example:

In html:

```
<button type="button" (focus)="disableUpArrowKey()">
```

In script:

```
disableUpArrowKey(){
    //??
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bind on `keydown` and call `preventDefault` of event.

html:

```
<button (keydown)="onKeydown($event)">Button</button>
```

ts:

```
...
onKeydown(event: KeyboardEvent) {
  if (event.key === 'ArrowUp') {
    event.preventDefault()
  }
}
...
```

stackblitz : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xmzct5

Comment: How to check if the element is focused in the above solution?

Comment: that event only occurred when button is focused