# aria-modal not supported in JAWS 18

Tags: javascript, html, angular, accessibility, wai-aria

Hi I am working on angular where we need popup accessibility.
I took reference from this link for that:

https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/examples/dialog-modal/dialog.html

It states that using aria-modal="true" will not allow screen readers read content which is in background but it is not working in JAWS 18 version and working in JAWS 19 version.

This is how my code looks like:

I have a dialog.component.html

```
<div aria-modal="true">
model-contet goes here
</div>
```

Now I am injecting this component `<dialog></dialog>` inside various components. But it still keeps reading content below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is correct but `aria-modal` is not well supported yet.

For now, you have to set `aria-hidden` on elements that do not belong to the dialog.  If your code/DOM can be arranged so that the dialog is a sibling of your main window, it makes setting `aria-hidden` much easier.

See my answer on [focus moving out of modal in scan mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53965676/focus-moving-out-of-modal-in-scan-mode/53972489#53972489)